# Python regexp: парсинг ini-файла

Tags: python, config

Есть простая задачка нужно спарсить ini файл ( значения формате <имя>=<значение>). Пример, ini:

```
[[config]]
controlPort=8900
idleTimeout=20
[[admin]]
login=petrovich
email=petrovich@zavod.ru
password=secret
```

Вот, что написал:

```
s=open('/home/archik/desk.ini', 'r')
for i in s.readlines():
    if i.startswith('['):
        continue
    else:
        p=re.compile('(?P<key>\S*(?==))')
        z=re.compile('(?P<znah>(?<==)\S*)')
        print (re.findall(p,i))
        print (re.findall(z,i))

s.close()
```

Хотелось бы объединить эти регулярные выражения в одно. Как это сделать?

Comment: уже не надо, решил: p=re.compile('(?P<key>\S*(?==))\S*(?P<znah>(?<==)\S*)')

Answer (score 2):

На будущее, обратите внимание, что в набор батареек входит [`configparser`](http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html):

```
import ConfigParser

config = ConfigParser.SafeConfigParser()
config.read("desk.ini")

# Еще пара скобок, т.к. у Вас они двойные.
print config.get("[config]", "controlPort")
```